# Filter files by string timestamp in filename

Tags: files, regular-expression, timestamps, filter

I've got a folder with several thousand files with names like ousjgforuigor-TIMESTAMP.txt

The timestamp is a standard Unix timestamp (e.g. 1543932635). Is there an easy way to list only files with a filename-timestamp > a provided one?

The number of characters before the timestamp is variable, but the name always ends with -TIMESTAMP.txt

I could write a bash script to do this, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [zsh's expression-as-a-glob-qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers),

```
t=1543951252 zsh -c 'datefilter() { ts=${REPLY##*-}; ts=${ts%*.txt}; ((ts >= $t)) }; print -l *-<->.txt(+datefilter)'
```

The overall command (towards the end) is `print -l`, which prints each argument on a separate line.  Well, the *overall* command is a presumed bash shell call to `zsh` that sets the environment variable `t` to some given value. Instead of printing the filenames, you could put them in an array or delete them or do anything else you want with them.

The glob qualifier `*-<->.txt` picks up potentially-matching filenames -- ones that begin with anything (`*`), followed by a dash (`-`), followed by any range of numbers (zsh's range operator `<->`), followed by `.txt`; that globbing is then sent to the glob qualifier `(+datefilter)`, which is a call to the corresponding function.

The `datefilter` function takes the incoming filename (in `$REPLY`) and prunes it down to the timestamp value. It returns true if that timestamp value is greater than or equal to the given timestamp in `t`. Files that succeed in that test are kept as filenames; the rest are dropped.

You could do something similar in bash by manually looping over the glob:

```
for f in *-*.txt
do 
  ts=${f##*-}
  ts=${ts%.txt}
  [[ ts -ge t ]] && printf '%s\n' "$f"
done
```

Although the bash wildcard `*` could pick up stray filenames such as `foo-bar.txt` where `bar` is not required to be a number. You'd have to hard-code in some assumptions otherwise, such as:

```
for f in *-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt; do # ...
```

or

```
for f in *-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.txt; do # ...
```

to force some number of digits to appear between the dash and the period.